# How to suppress inlining of templates with gcov

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, gcov

I'm using GCC 4.9 with GCOV to get code and branch coverage. However, the results for branch coverage are utterly useless for my C++ code. It seems GCC inlines templates despite using all `-fno-*-inline` flags I know of.

Here is a small example application that illustrates the problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string foo;
  foo = "abc";
  cout << foo << endl;
}
```

I compile the program with `g++ -O0 -fno-inline -fno-inline-small-functions -fno-default-inline --coverage -fprofile-arcs test.cpp -o test`

After running `test`, `gcovr -r . -b` prints:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           GCC Code Coverage Report
Directory: .
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File                                    Branches   Taken  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test.cpp                                      14       7    50%   7,8,9,10
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                         14       7    50%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There is not a single branch in our `main` function. For example, line 7 contains `string foo;`. It seems the constructor of `std::basic_string<...>` has some if statement in it, but that's not useful information when looking at the coverage of `main`.

The problem is that all these inlined branches sum up and the branch coverage calculated for my actual unit tests are about 40% as a result. I'm interested in the branch coverage of my code, as opposed to how much branches I hit in the C++ standard library.

Is there any way to completely shut down inlining in the compiler or to tell GCOV to not consider inlined branches? I couldn't find any guide on the GCOV homepage or someplace else regarding that topic.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: And what do the gcov output files show? All the std library code will be attributed to `test.cpp` in the summary even without inlining, but the detailed output should show which actual functions the branches occur in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you should always double-check your expectations. Thanks a lot @Useless for pointing me to the `gcov` output itself. You weren't quite right, though: the branches are not attributed to the `test.cpp` file. Running `gcovr` with `-k` and looking at all the intermediate files shows that `gcov` correctly produces files such as `#usr#include#c++#4.9#bits#basic_string.h.gcov` that show coverage for the C++ standard library side of things.

However, the reason for all the branches in `test.cpp` is not inlining. It's *exceptions*. Each call into the standard library is a branch because of potential exceptions (e.g. `std::bad_alloc`). Adding `-fno-exceptions` to the compiler flags gives the following output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           GCC Code Coverage Report
Directory: .
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File                                    Branches   Taken  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test.cpp                                       4       2    50%   10
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                          4       2    50%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Digging deeper into the `gcov` output via `cat foo.cpp.gcov` prints:

```
        -:    0:Source:test.cpp
        -:    0:Graph:/home/neverlord/gcov/test.gcno
        -:    0:Data:/home/neverlord/gcov/test.gcda
        -:    0:Runs:1
        -:    0:Programs:1
        -:    1:#include <string>
        -:    2:#include <iostream>
        -:    3:
        -:    4:using namespace std;
        -:    5:
function main called 1 returned 100% blocks executed 100%
        1:    6:int main() {
        1:    7:  string foo;
call    0 returned 1
        1:    8:  foo = "abc";
call    0 returned 1
        1:    9:  cout << foo << endl;
call    0 returned 1
call    1 returned 1
call    2 returned 1
function _GLOBAL__sub_I_main called 1 returned 100% blocks executed 100%
function _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii called 1 returned 100% blocks executed 100%
        4:   10:}
call    0 returned 1
branch  1 taken 1 (fallthrough)
branch  2 taken 0
branch  3 taken 1 (fallthrough)
branch  4 taken 0
```

Sorry for the noise.